# Query by field value, not value in field array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The following snippet shows three queries:

- find all the documents
- find the documents containing a field `a` containing either the string `"x"` or an array containing the string `"x"`
- find the documents containing a field `a` containing an array containing the string `"x"`

I was not able to find the documents containing a field `a` containing the string `"x"`, not inside an array.

```
> db.stuff.find({},{_id:0})
{ "a" : "x" }
{ "a" : [ "x" ] }
> db.stuff.find({a:"x"},{_id:0})
{ "a" : "x" }
{ "a" : [ "x" ] }
> db.stuff.find({a:{$elemMatch:{$eq:"x"}}},{_id:0})
{ "a" : [ "x" ] }
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB basically does not care if the data at a "given path" is actually in an array or not. If you want to make the distinction, then you need to "tell it that":

```
db.stuff.find({ "a": "x", "$where": "return !Array.isArray(this.a)" })
```

This is what [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) adds to the bargain, where you can supply a condition that explicitly asks "is this an array" via [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) in JavaScript evaluation. And the JavaScript NOT `!` assertion reverses the logic.

An alternate approach is to add the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) check:

```
db.stuff.find({ "a": "x", "a.0": { "$exists": false } })
```

Which also essentially asks "is this an array" by looking for the first element index. So the "reverse" `false` case means "this is not an array".

Or even as you note you can use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to select only the array, but "negate" that using [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/):

```
db.stuff.find({ "a": { "$not": { "$elemMatch": { "$eq": "x" } } } })
```

Though probably "not" the best of options since that also "negates index usage", which the other examples all strive to avoid by at least including "one" positive condition for a match. So it's for the best to include the "implicit AND" by combining arguments:

```
db.stuff.find({
  "a": { "$eq": "x", "$not": { "$elemMatch": { "$eq": "x" } } } 
})
```

Or for "aggregation" which does not support [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), you can test using the [`$isArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/isArray/) aggregation operator should your MongoDB version ( 3.2 or greater ) support it:

```
db.stuff.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "a": "x" } },
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": { "$not": { "$isArray": "$a" } },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

Noting that it is good practice to supply "regular" query conditions as well where possible, and in all cases.

> Also noting that querying the BSON [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#querying-by-array-type) does not typically work in this case, since the "contents" of the array itself are in fact a "string", which is what the [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#querying-by-array-type) operator is going to consider, and thus not report that such an array is in fact an array.

Comment: Thanks! I think the answer with `a.0` should be used when possible because it will use an index if present, while the `$where` can't. Also, the `return` keyword is useless.

Comment: @stenci It's not "useless", it's just that `$where` considers it to be "implied", but "good language practice" ( which I'm used to doing ) actually suggests you "should" in fact always `return` from any function. Note that even in this form the `function()` is essentially "implied" as well.